# What do associations do in the IntelliJ IDEA setup?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I looked at YouTube setups and they all didn't pick the associations on the setup.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are referring to these options in the Windows installer:

[image: create associations]

it will associate the files with the IDE in the system so that when you click on the files with these extensions in your file manager (Windows Explorer), they will open in the IDE.